# Populate a key tuple and value in dictionary from lists in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, tuples

I have three large lists that want to use to populate a key and value of a dictionary in Python. Here a small example of the first part:

```
i = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
j = [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Cost = [13, 12, 13, 15, 13]
```

My goal is to combine i and j into a tuple key and cost as a value, like this:

```
Data = {(i[0],j[0]): cost[0], (i[1],j[1]): cost[1], }
```

I've searched but I have not found any good solution. So does someone know how to populate the dictionary and tuple through a loop or something like that? The goal is to achieve this:

```
Data = {(0, 2): 13, (1, 0): 12, (2, 0): 13, (3, 0): 15, (4, 0): 13}
```

Tnx!

Comment: I would think loop would work perfectly fine. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: No a loop was not possible

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary comprehension after [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)ping 'em all:

```
>>> {(k1, k2): val for k1, k2, val in zip(i, j, Cost)}
{(0, 2): 13, (1, 0): 12, (2, 0): 13, (3, 0): 15, (4, 0): 13}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same zip inbuilt function as mentioned by Moses Koledoye.
Something like this:

`dict(zip(zip(i,j),Cost))`

Result :

`{(3, 0): 15, (2, 0): 13, (1, 0): 12, (0, 2): 13, (4, 0): 13}`

This will be faster than dict of list comprehension of zip function.

Comment: If you are satisfied with any of the answers you may accept that answer by clickeing the tick icon in the answers.